# Is there a way to change the slider animation speed?

Tags: amp-html

i'm building amp website and i used an amp-carousel: 
https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-carousel/
https://www.ampproject.org/es/docs/reference/components/amp-carousel

I'm using the carousel with the "slides" and "autoplay" options as a main banner for the homepage and i'm trying to change the animation speed when it advances slides.

Is there a way to set the animation speed or is there a feature request for this?

Answer (score 3):

Transition speed doesn't seem to be supported at the moment. I'm facing the same issue and couldn't find any documentation or attributes to control the animation speed. The default value is too fast and doesn't look very good

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the carousel and use the amp selector to create your own. Not the cleanest way but at least you have full control.

```css
.carouselWrapper{
    position: relative;
}

.carouselOverideSlider{
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carouselOverideSlider li[aria-selected="true"] amp-img{
    transition: transform 15s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.carouselOverideSlider li[option][selected] {
    opacity:1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
.carouselOverideSlider li{
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.carouselOverideSlider ul, .carouselOverideSlider li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.dots-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:110;
}
.dots {
    max-width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
}
.dots li {
    width:13px;
    height:13px;
    margin:13px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    display:inline-block;
}
.dots li[option][selected] {
    outline:0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border:1px solid #1da838;
    background:#fff;
}
.amp-carousel-button{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="This is the AMP Boilerplate.">
        <link rel="preload" as="script" href="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js">
        <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
        <script async custom-element="amp-animation" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-animation-0.1.js"></script>
        <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.2.js"></script>
        <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
        <!-- Import other AMP Extensions here -->
        <style amp-custom>
            /* Add your styles here */
        </style>
        <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
        <noscript>
            <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style>
        </noscript>
        <link rel="canonical" href=".">
        <title>My AMP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="carouselWrapper">
        <amp-carousel id="custom-button"
            width="800"
            height="533"
            layout="responsive"
            type="slides"
            autoplay
            delay="5000"
            on="slideChange:
            debbie.toggle(index=event.index, value=true),
            dalas.toggle(index=event.index, value=true)">
            <amp-img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/View_from_Reunion_Tower_August_2015_13.jpg/800px-View_from_Reunion_Tower_August_2015_13.jpg"
                width="800"
                height="533"
                layout="responsive"
                alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
            <amp-img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Flag_of_Dallas.svg/800px-Flag_of_Dallas.svg.png"
                width="800"
                height="533"
                layout="responsive"
                alt="another sample image"></amp-img>
        </amp-carousel>
        <div class="carouselOverideSlider">
            <amp-selector id="dalas">
                <ul  class="">
                    <li option="0" selected>
                        <amp-img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/View_from_Reunion_Tower_August_2015_13.jpg/800px-View_from_Reunion_Tower_August_2015_13.jpg"
                            width="800"
                            height="533"
                            layout="responsive"
                            alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
                    </li>
                    <li option="1">
                        <amp-img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Flag_of_Dallas.svg/800px-Flag_of_Dallas.svg.png"
                            width="800"
                            height="533"
                            layout="responsive"
                            alt="another sample image"></amp-img>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </amp-selector>
        </div>
        <div class="dots-container">
            <amp-selector id="debbie"
                on="select:custom-button.goToSlide(index=event.targetOption)"
                layout="container">
                <ul id="carouselDots" class="dots">
                    <li option="0" selected></li>
                    <li option="1"></li>
                </ul>
            </amp-selector>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest answer we can get with regard to carousel speed :

The autoplay property must be on and the default slide interval, which I think is the speed you're referring to, is 5 seconds. You can override this using the delay attribute.

> [autoplay
> (optional)](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-carousel#autoplay-(optional))
>
> Advances the slide to the next slide without user interaction.
>
> If present:
>
> **By default, advances a slide in 5000 millisecond intervals (5
> seconds); this can be overridden by the delay attribute**. Attaches the
> loop attribute to amp-carousel if loop is not already present.
> Requires at least 3 slides for autoplay to occur. Applies only to
> carousels with type=slides. delay (optional) Specifies the duration
> (in milliseconds) to delay advancing to the next slide when autoplay
> is enabled. The delay attribute is only applicable to carousels with
> type=slides.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i understand correctly you can determine the delay between the slides but not the transition between slides which is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can use fade for slide transition which I found [here](https://codepen.io/aghassemi/pen/MQXZXa).
That's not bad :)

```
.amp-carousel-slide {
opacity:0;
}
.amp-carousel-slide[aria-hidden=false] {
transition:opacity 1s;
opacity:1;
```

But, if you use *image gallery* in the `amp-carousel`, the opacity must be changed into `0.4` or more. Otherwise, the *image preview* **will not show**. :v

Example:

```
.amp-carousel-slide {opacity:0.7;}
```

[image]

More ... (still in image preview of image gallery), to make it good look, we can add:

```
.amp-carousel-slide:hover{
opacity:1;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

on pointer hover.